# Failed to load plugin 'vue' declared in '.eslintrc.cjs

Tags: typescript, eslint, nuxtjs3

Anyone, please help me

After installing @nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript into my Nuxt project and configure it in .eslintrc.cjs I get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Failed to load plugin 'vue' declared in '.eslintrc.cjs » @nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript » @nuxtjs/eslint-config': Unexpected token '.'
Referenced from: /home/vladislav.chugunov@intexsoft.by/IdeaProjects/seasonvar-nuxt/node_modules/@nuxtjs/eslint-config/index.js

/home/vladislav.chugunov@intexsoft.by/IdeaProjects/seasonvar-nuxt/node_modules/eslint-plugin-vue/lib/rules/no-restricted-component-names.js:119
const componentName = property.value.value?.toString()
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
at Module.\_compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
at Object.Module.\_extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
at Function.Module.\_load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
at Object.\<anonymous\> (/home/vladislav.chugunov@intexsoft.by/IdeaProjects/seasonvar-nuxt/node_modules/eslint-plugin-vue/lib/index.js:122:38)
at Module.\_compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
at Object.Module.\_extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
Process finished with exit code -1
```

How can I fix this?

node: v16.18.1
yarn: 1.22.1

My packages

```
{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext \".ts,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint:prettier": "prettier --check .",
    "lint": "yarn lint:js && yarn lint:prettier",
    "lintfix": "prettier --write --list-different . && yarn lint:js --fix"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/devtools": "latest",
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.17.1",
    "@nuxt/typescript-build": "^3.0.1",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.16.19",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.11",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "nuxt": "^3.6.5",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.64.0",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "pinia": "^2.1.4"
  }
}
```

My .eslintrc.cjs

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    browser: true,
    node: true,
  },
  parser: 'vue-eslint-parser',
  extends: ['@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript'],
  plugins: [],
  rules: {},
};
```

I haven't found anything on the internet that can help me with this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just encountered the same error. I'm using PhpStorm with Vite, Vue, and TypeScript. **I resolved the issue by updating my Node.js interpreter to a version above 14, as the optional chaining operator (?.) requires ECMAScript 2020 support, which is available in Node.js versions 16 or above**

Previously, my PhpStorm was using a Node.js interpreter version 14 or below. If you're using a JetBrains IDE like PhpStorm and comes with default setting for the node interpreter version, this solution might help you too. Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Yes, indeed, I had an interpreter of version 12, I changed it to 16 and the error disappeared

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a syntax error in the ESLint configuration file of you app. I published a [boiler plate](https://github.com/ReaganM02/Nuxt3-Boiler-Plate) for Nuxt 3 with eslint types configured. I am using the same module and it is working for me. Hope that helps you.

Comment: Even with your configuration, I have the same error. I did a little investigation and it turned out that this error only appears on my laptop. I will look in this direction

Comment: Are you still getting the same error? I would suggest to try to create a new nuxt project and manually add the modules you need and carefully check which are causing the issue.

Comment: This is how I did my project, I added all the packages manually. When adding @nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript to extends in the eslint config, this error appears